# Dynamodb range_key get's rounded

Tags: rounding, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I am using boto (on windows) to create a new item in a dynamodb table, I set the range key to 129271300103.3986 but in the database it is set to 129271300103
is this a boto issue, or dynamodb issue?

EDIT: it is not just floats, large integers get chopped off as well,
I submit 129271300103398600
but I get 129271300103000000

Comment: See https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/1060 for a lengthy conversion about this.  Please feel free to chime in on that issue with your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about boto, but make sure your Marshaling of Object to DB string doesn't round it off.

Comment: I don't understand, I am passing the float (or the large int) to the boto function, is there still room for me here to mess something up in the conversion or it's just boto?